# 2gis floor widget webview does not work correctly in Xiaomi mi 9t

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, crash, xiaomi

I have a problem with loading 2gis floor widget webview in Xiaomi mi 9t (android X).
Оn the screenshots you can see that the points are not shown properly.

[no places and interface buttons loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5NSd.png) (on xiaomi)

[everything is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dqnF.png) (on huawey p30 lite)

This is the code i used for it:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class MollMapFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_moll_map) {

companion object {
    private const val MAP_HTML = "file:///android_asset/2gis/complex_map.html"
    private const val ASK_PERMISSIONS_DELAY = 200L
}

//ViewModel
private val mollMapViewModel by viewModels<MollMapViewModel>()

//Bottom sheet dialog popup
private val bottomSheetPopup: BottomSheetDialog by lazy {
    BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), R.style.MollMapBottomSheetDialog).apply {
        setContentView(requireActivity().layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_marker_info, null))
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    Handler().postDelayed(
            {
                if (checkLocationAndForegroundServicePermissions()) {
                    mollMapViewModel.getLocationAndPlaces(false)
                } else {
                    requestLocationAndForegroundServicePermissions()
                }
            },
            ASK_PERMISSIONS_DELAY
    )

    initWebView()

    initObservers()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    bottomSheetPopup.hide()
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (checkLocationAndForegroundServicePermissions()) {
        mollMapViewModel.askGeoPush()
    }
    mollMapViewModel.getLocationAndPlaces(true)
}

private fun showGeoPushPermission() = requireContext().showGeoPopup(
        {
            mollMapViewModel.sendGeoPushRequestAnswer(true)

            GeoPushWorker.switchGeoPushWorker(context = requireContext(), isAfterLocationRequest = true)
        },
        { mollMapViewModel.sendGeoPushRequestAnswer(false) }
)

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private fun initWebView() {
    web_view.apply {
        with(settings) {
            setSupportZoom(true)
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            domStorageEnabled = true
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
            allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
            allowContentAccess = true
            setAppCacheEnabled(false)
            cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE

            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            useWideViewPort = true
            builtInZoomControls = true
            displayZoomControls = false
            defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
        }

        addJavascriptInterface(MapCallback(), "Callback")
    }
}

private fun initObservers() {
    with(mollMapViewModel) {
        getPlacesLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { loadable ->
            updateUi(loadable,
                    successAction = { places ->
                        places?.let {
                            val complexId = getComplexId()
                            if (complexId.isNotEmpty()
                                    && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                showBuilding(complexId, places)
                        } ?: showPlacesNotLoadedError()
                    },
                    errorAction = {
                        handleCustomException(
                                exception = it,
                                networkOfflineAction = {
                                    showPlacesNotLoadedError()
                                },
                                serverExceptionAction = { _, _ ->
                                    showToast(R.string.error_server)
                                }
                        )
                    }
            )
        })

        getPlaceRulesLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { loadable ->
            updateUi(loadable,
                    successAction = { rules ->
                        rules?.let {
                            showPlaceRules(it)
                        }
                    },
                    errorAction = {
                        handleCustomException(
                                exception = it,
                                networkOfflineAction = {
                                    showToast(R.string.error_connection)
                                },
                                serverExceptionAction = {_,_ ->
                                    showToast(R.string.error_server)
                                })
                    })
        })

        getSelectedPlaceLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { place ->
            place?.let {
                setPlaceInfo(it)
                bottomSheetPopup.show()
            }
        })

        getGeoPushPermissionShowFlag().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { loadable ->
            updateUi(loadable,
                    successAction = { needToShow ->
                        needToShow?.let {
                            if (it) showGeoPushPermission()
                        } ?: showToast(R.string.error_connection)
                    },
                    errorAction = {
                        handleCustomException(it, networkOfflineAction = {
                            showToast(R.string.error_connection)
                        })
                    })
        })
    }
}

private fun showBuilding(complexId: String, places: List<Place>) {
    web_view.apply {
        progress_map.enable()
        webViewClient = MollMapWebViewClient(complexId, places)
        loadUrl(MAP_HTML)
    }
}


private fun showSharing(place: Place) {
    val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = MapFragment.SHARING_INTENT_TYPE
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                getString(R.string.place_sharing_message, place.title, place.getAddressTextShort())
        )
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.share)))
}

private fun focusFirm(firmId: String) {
    web_view.post {
        web_view.loadUrl("javascript:showFirm('${firmId}')")
    }
}

private fun showPlaceRules(rules: String) {
    bottomSheetPopup.place_rules.text = rules
}

private fun showContacts(phone: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).apply {
        data = Uri.parse("tel:$phone")
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun showRouteScreen(place: Place) {
    val intent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + place.getLat() + "," + place.getLng())
    ).apply {
        setPackage(MapFragment.GOOGLE_PACKAGE)
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(requireContext().packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        requireContext().showToast(MapFragment.GOOGLE_ERROR_TOAST)
    }
}

private fun setPlaceInfo(place: Place) {
    bottomSheetPopup.place_name.text = place.title
    bottomSheetPopup.place_address.text = place.getAddressTextShortWithoutCity()
    mollMapViewModel.getPlaceRules(place.id ?: 0)
    setPlaceDistance(place)
    setPlaceRating(place)

    val phone = place.phone ?: ""
    if (phone.isBlank()) {
        bottomSheetPopup.call_button.disable()
    } else {
        bottomSheetPopup.call_button.enable()
        bottomSheetPopup.call_button.setOnClickListener { showContacts(phone) }
    }

    bottomSheetPopup.place_share_button.setOnClickListener { showSharing(place) }
    bottomSheetPopup.route_button.setOnClickListener { showRouteScreen(place) }

    bottomSheetPopup.marker_info.setOnClickListener {
        (activity as MainActivity).openPlaceFullScreenDialog(placeItem = place)
    }
}

private fun setPlaceDistance(place: Place) {
    var dist = getString(R.string.distance, place.distance.toInt().toString())

    place.distance.let {
        bottomSheetPopup.place_distance.enable()
        if (it > 100000f || it <= 0.0) {
            bottomSheetPopup.place_distance.disable()
        } else if (it > 1000f) {
            dist = if (place.distance.toInt() % 1000 == 0) {
                getString(R.string.distance_km, String.format("%.0f", (place.distance / 1000f)))
            } else {
                getString(R.string.distance_km, String.format("%.2f", (place.distance / 1000f)))
            }
        }
        bottomSheetPopup.place_distance.text = dist
    }
}

private fun setPlaceRating(place: Place) {
    bottomSheetPopup.place_rating.rating = 0f
    place.rating?.let {
        bottomSheetPopup.place_rating.rating = if (it.isEmpty()) 5f else it.toFloat()
    }
}

private fun showPlacesNotLoadedError() = showToast(R.string.places_load_error)

private inner class MapCallback {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun onFirmSelected(firmIds: String) {
        Log.d("onFirmSelected", "ids: $firmIds")
        focusFirm(firmIds)
        mollMapViewModel.setSelectedPlace(firmIds)
    }
}

private inner class MollMapWebViewClient(
        private val complexId: String,
        private val places: List<Place>
) : WebViewClient() {

    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        Log.d("wvclient", "onPageStarted: $url")
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        Log.d("wvclient", "onPageFinished: $url")
        var styleString = ""
        places.forEach {
            if (it.gisFirmId.isNotEmpty()){
                //Добавление строки стиля для конкретного id
                styleString += ",'${it.gisFirmId}':{color:0xbf6d60,highlightColor:0xaf5d50}"
            }
        }
        //функция js с настройкой стиля, которую мы передаем в качестве строки
        val style = "( function() { return {backgroundColor:0xd8ccc3,defaultIndoor:{color:0xe6e6e6},defaultOutdoor:{color:0xd8ccc3},0:{color:0xfafafa},110200:{color:0xe6e6e6}${styleString}}; } )()"
        view?.loadUrl("javascript:loadMap('${complexId}', ${style})")
    }

    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
        val url = request?.url.toString()
        Log.d("wvclient", "shouldInterceptRequest: ${request?.url}, headers: ${request?.requestHeaders}")

        if (url.contains("floorGeometries")) {
            val connection = URL(url).openConnection()
            val `is` = connection.getInputStream()

            val res = String(`is`.readBytes())
            Log.d("floorGeometries", res)
            val correctedMap = GisFloorsHelper.distinguishFirms(res, places)
            val correctedResponse = correctedMap.first
            mollMapViewModel.onMapRendered(places)

            val ret = WebResourceResponse(
                    "application/json",
                    "utf-8",
                    correctedResponse.byteInputStream(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
            ).apply {
                responseHeaders = connection.headerFields.map { it.key to it.value.first() }.toMap()
            }

            activity?.runOnUiThread { progress_map.disable() }
            return ret
        }

        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
    }

    override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        Log.d("wvclient.onLoadResource", "url: $url")
        super.onLoadResource(view, url)
    }

    override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler, er: SslError?) {
        handler.proceed()
    }

}

}
```

viewmodelclass:

```
class MollMapViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

private val placesUc by inject<PlacesUc>()

private var places: List<Place>? = null

//Job
private var placeRulesJob: Job? = null
private var placesJob: Job? = null
private var showGeoPushPermissionJob: Job? = null

//liveData
private val selectedPlaceLiveData = MutableLiveData<Place?>()
private val placesLiveData = MutableLiveData<Loadable<List<Place>?>>()
private val needToShowGeoPushPermissionLiveData = MutableLiveData<Loadable<Boolean?>>()
private val placeRulesLiveData = MutableLiveData<Loadable<String?>>()

fun getPlacesLiveData(): LiveData<Loadable<List<Place>?>> = placesLiveData

fun getPlaceRulesLiveData(): LiveData<Loadable<String?>> = placeRulesLiveData

fun getSelectedPlaceLiveData(): LiveData<Place?> = selectedPlaceLiveData

fun getGeoPushPermissionShowFlag(): LiveData<Loadable<Boolean?>> = needToShowGeoPushPermissionLiveData

fun onMapRendered(places: List<Place>) {
    if (places.size < this.places?.size ?: 0) return
    this.places = places
}

fun setSelectedPlace(firmId: String) {
    selectedPlaceLiveData.postValue(places?.findLast { it.gisFirmId == firmId })
}

fun getLocationAndPlaces(forceUpdate: Boolean) {
    val locationManager = App.context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    val userLocation: UserLocation? = placesUc.getCurrentUserLocation(lm = locationManager)

    if (userLocation != null) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            placesUc.saveLocation(userLocation)

            getPlaces(userLocation, forceUpdate)
        } else {
            placesUc.removeLocation()

            getPlaces(null, forceUpdate)
        }
    } else {
        if (App.context.checkLocationPermission()) {
            LocationServices
                    .getFusedLocationProviderClient(App.context)
                    .lastLocation
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        val lastLocation = task.result

                        if (lastLocation != null) {
                            getPlaces(UserLocation(lastLocation.latitude, lastLocation.longitude), forceUpdate)
                        } else {
                            getPlaces(null, forceUpdate)
                        }
                    }
        } else {
            getPlaces(null, forceUpdate)
        }
    }
}

fun getComplexId() = CloneUtils.getComplexId()

fun getPlaces(userLocation: UserLocation?, forceUpdate: Boolean) {
    if (checkJob(placesJob)) {
        placesJob = launchLoadingErrorJob(context = Dispatchers.IO, liveData = placesLiveData) {
            placesUc.getPlaces(userLocation, forceUpdate)
        }
    }
}

fun askGeoPush() {
    if (checkJob(showGeoPushPermissionJob)) {
        showGeoPushPermissionJob = launchLoadingErrorJob(
                context = Dispatchers.IO,
                liveData = needToShowGeoPushPermissionLiveData
        ) {
            placesUc.doWeNeedToAskForGeoPush()
        }
    }
}

fun sendGeoPushRequestAnswer(answer: Boolean) {
    placesUc.geoPushRequestGotAnswer(answer)
}

fun getPlaceRules(id: Int) {
    if (checkJob(placeRulesJob)) {
        placeRulesJob = launchLoadingErrorJob(context = Dispatchers.IO, liveData = placeRulesLiveData) {
            val placeUnitList = placesUc.getPlaceUnitList(id)
            val rules = StringBuilder()
            if (placeUnitList.isNotEmpty()) {
                placeUnitList.forEach { unit ->
                    if (unit == placeUnitList.last() ||
                            unit.title?.last() == '.' ||
                            unit.title?.last() == '!') {
                        rules.append(unit.title)
                    } else {
                        rules.append("${unit.title}. ")
                    }
                }
            }
            rules.toString()
        }
    }
}

}
```

And some additional code

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_map"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_moll" />

</FrameLayout>
```

my html file for access 2gis api:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://floors-widget.api.2gis.ru/loader.js"
    id="dg-floors-widget-loader">
</script>
<script charset="utf-8">
var widget;

function loadMap(complexId, style) {
console.log(style)
widget = DG.FloorsWidget.init({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    initData: {
        complexId: complexId,
        options: {
            hideSearchPanel: true,
            locale: 'ru_RU',
            initialZoom: 17,
            minZoom: 17,
            maxZoom: 19.5,
            //rotatable: false,
            initialRotation: 0.45,
            resetStyle: true,
            initialFloor: 1,
            style: style
        }
    }
});

document.body.style.margin = "0px";

//Событие по клику на точку
//Отдает массив из id точек
widget.on('click', (event) => {
    let message = {"firmIds": event.firmIds };
    let str = (event.firmIds).toString();
    Callback.onFirmSelected(str);
    webkit.messageHandlers.handler.postMessage(message);
});
}

//Функция открывающая конкретную точку, если необходимо так же переключает этаж
function showFirm(firmId) {
    widget.focusOnFirm(firmId);
}

//Функция поиска, с помощью нее можно фильтровать точки по категориям
function searchQuery(string) {
    widget.search(string);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would help many if you can post code as text and not images.

Comment: added all code u need. Waiting for reply